# ORA-12560:TNS:Protocol adapter error in OracleService ORCL is still running

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-connection, sqlplus

[image]

I use `sqlplus` to try to connect `/ as sysdba`.

I tried to set `oracle_sid=ORCL`, but it's not better.

I Google[d] for this error but not able to find the actual reason and how to solve this error ?

> ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adaptor error

Can anyone tell me a perfect solution to solve login problem.

Comment: how are you connecting .

Comment: @NullSoulException i can't connect oracle

Comment: @user3722548 do you connect via sqlplus or any other software? Do you have an XE? If yes, then there should be 2 services - oracle instance and listener. Try stopping both and start listener first and instance after it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have both the listener and the database services up, then you will get this error.

From your post, `OracleServiceORCL` is running. Now you need to check for this service: `OracleHOMENAMETNSListener` (where `HOMENAME` is the name of your oracle home). Find it and start it if it's not running.

If they are both running, then try bouncing the listener service. If that doesn't do it, try bouncing the database service. (BUT: if any other users could be connected, DO NOT bounce either service as that will kick them out.)

If that doesn't do it then run `lsnrctl status` and `lsnrctl services` to check whether the listener is coming up properly and listening for ORCL.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar error few days ago .  Here is what I did:

1. Checked the status of listener. It was up and running.
2. Checked oracle services.  It was up and started.
3. So what I did next is bouncing the services and the issue then was resolved.

Comment: "bounce the services"  , can you tell cleanly what i have to do, please? 
thank you very much.

Comment: What I meant by bouncing is, restart the services.